# WebApi 2nd parameter binding

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi like the code. I want to add second parameter userId to the webapi How can I do this without changing the current style?

```
public class MeslekUzmanlikApi
{
    public decimal? PrmMeslekKayitNo { get; set; }
    public decimal? PrmMeslekUzmanlikKayitNo { get; set; }
    public string Meslek { get; set; }
}

public class MeslekUzmanlikApiController : BaseApiController
{
    private static List<MeslekUzmanlikApi> _MeslekUzmanlik;
    private List<MeslekUzmanlikApi> MeslekUzmanlik
    {
        get
        {
            if (_MeslekUzmanlik == null)
            {
                _MeslekUzmanlik = MeslekBLL.Instance.ReadAllMeslekUzmanlik().AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
                {
                    return new MeslekUzmanlikApi
                    {
                        Meslek = row["MESLEK"].ToString(),
                        PrmMeslekKayitNo = (row["PRMMESLEKKAYITNO"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToDecimal(row["PRMMESLEKKAYITNO"]) : default(decimal?),
                        PrmMeslekUzmanlikKayitNo = (row["PRMMESLEKUZMANLIKKAYITNO"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToDecimal(row["PRMMESLEKUZMANLIKKAYITNO"]) : default(decimal?)
                    };
                }).ToList();
            }

            return _MeslekUzmanlik;
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("MeslekUzmanlik")]
    public IEnumerable<MeslekUzmanlikApi> GetMeslekUzmanlikByMeslekAd(string aciklama)
    {
        return MeslekUzmanlik.Where(a => a.Meslek.ToLower(Util.Culture.TR).Replace("â", "a")
                             .Contains(Util.StringEncoder.DecodeForApi(aciklama.ToLower(Util.Culture.TR))));
    }
```

I want to add userId here GetMeslekUzmanlikByMeslekAd(string aciklama, decimal userId) how will be the inside ? and where I called webapi is as follows:

```
var initAutoComplete
    = (function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=txt.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {

                    var host = "";
                    if (window.location.hostname == "localhost") {
                        host = '<%=GetBaseUrl()%>';
                        }
                        else {
                            host = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
                        }
                    //var encodedterm = HtmlEncodeApi(request.term);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: host + "/api/meslekuzmanlikapi/meslekuzmanlik/" + stripNonAlphaNumeric(request.term),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.Meslek,
                                    valueMeslek: item.PrmMeslekKayitNo,
                                    valueMeslekUzmanlik: item.PrmMeslekUzmanlikKayitNo
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                autoFill: true,
                minLength: 3,
                delay: 500,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#<%=txt.ClientID %>").val("");
                    $("#<%=hdnMeslekKayitNo.ClientID %>").val("");
                    $("#<%=hdnMeslekUzmanlikKayitNo.ClientID %>").val("");
                    if (ui.item) {
                        if (ui.item.label) {
                            $("#<%=txt.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.label);
                        }
                        if (ui.item.valueMeslek) {
                            $("#<%=hdnMeslekKayitNo.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.valueMeslek.toString());
                        }
                        if (ui.item.valueMeslekUzmanlik) {
                            $("#<%=hdnMeslekUzmanlikKayitNo.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.valueMeslekUzmanlik.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    CallServer();
                    return false;
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#<%=txt.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                },
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#<%=hdn.ClientID %>").val("");
                    $("#<%=hdnMeslekKayitNo.ClientID %>").val("");
                    $("#<%=hdnMeslekUzmanlikKayitNo.ClientID %>").val("");
                    $("#<%=txt.ClientID %>").val("");
                    $("#<%=divMeslekUzmanlik.ClientID %>").hide();
                },
                open: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                var newText = String(item.label).replace(
                    new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
                    "<span class='ui-state-highlight'>$&</span>");
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a>" + newText + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        });
    });
```

How will be corresponding url call ? url: host + "/api/meslekuzmanlikapi/meslekuzmanlik/" + stripNonAlphaNumeric(request.term),
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! We can do this.

First, update `GetMeslekUzmanlikByMeslekAd` to accept the new parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("MeslekUzmanlik")]
public IEnumerable<MeslekUzmanlikApi> GetMeslekUzmanlikByMeslekAd(string aciklama, decimal userId)
{
    // Use userId parameter as required in your function. For example, if you want to filter the results by userId.
    // For the sake of this example, I will not modify the behavior further.

    return MeslekUzmanlik.Where(a => a.Meslek.ToLower(Util.Culture.TR).Replace("â", "a")
                             .Contains(Util.StringEncoder.DecodeForApi(aciklama.ToLower(Util.Culture.TR))));
}
```

Then update your jQuery:

```
url: host + "/api/meslekuzmanlikapi/meslekuzmanlik/" + stripNonAlphaNumeric(request.term) + "?userId=" + currentUserId,
```

NOTE:

1. Make sure you have `currentUserId` set to a valid value before making the AJAX call.
2. Double check your web api config allows for attribute routing or it may not work correctly.

Hope this helps!